# Erro no autocomplete de um input

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, estou tentando fazer um autocomplete no campo valor unitário de acordo com o nome do produto escolhido no select, options do select preenchidos de acordo com os produtos do banco de dados

[image: exemplo]
[image: exemplo]
[image: exemplo]

A lógica que desenvolvi foi executar uma query no PHP que seleciona descricao e preco_venda e preenche a tag  sendo value = preco_venda e conteúdo da option recebendo descricao.
Em seguida usei o DOM do javascript para pegar o value da opção escolhida no evento "onblur" e uma variável PHP recebe esse conteúdo.
Com a variável PHP recebendo o value, queria preencher esse valor no campo unitário

```
 <label>Produto: </label><br>

        <select name="nomeproduto" onblur="valorSelect()">
            <option value=""></option>

            <?php 
                $sql = "select descricao, preco_venda from produtos";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
            
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rows['preco_venda']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $rows['descricao']; ?>
                    </option>

          <?php } ?>
            
        </select><br><br>

        <?php
                      
        $valor =
            "<script>
                function valorSelect() {
                    let valor = document.querySelector('select').value;
                    document.write(valor);
                } 
            </script>";  
        ?>

        <label>Valor unitário: </label><br>
        <input type="number" name="valorunitario" value="<?php echo $valor; ?>">
```

Mas ocorre esses erros:
[image: erros]

Quem puder ajudar a corrigir esses erros estarei muito grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá, você está tentando passar a variável `$valor` para o `value` de um input. Esse é o primeiro erro, pois a variável não vai ser o valor da execução dessa função, e sim a string que foi declarada dentro dela. Desse modo, o javascript não reconhece que existe uma função chamada `valorSelect()`, que é o erro apontado no seu console.

Vale lembrar também, que não é possível pegar um valor de dentro de um bloco javascript, enquanto o seu documento é carregado pelo browser.

O que você deve fazer é criar essa função fora do php, diretamente no HTML, como no exemplo a seguir.

```js
    var select = document.querySelector('select');
    var input = document.querySelector('input');

    select.onchange = function(e) {
        var value = e.target.value;
        input.value = value;
    }
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="">Escolher</input>
    <option value="12.000">Pc gamer</option>
    <option value="7.000">Notebook</option>
    <option value="500">Cadeira gamer</option>
</select><br />

<input />
```

Uma observação, é que você não vai conseguir obter o produto que a pessoa escolheu dessa forma, e só o valor dele.

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o problema, mas vou testar sua lógica

Como resolvi:
<select name="nomeproduto" onblur="valorSelect()">

function valorSelect() {
                        let valor = event.target;
                        valor = parseFloat(valor.value)

                        let exibir = document.getElementById('preco')
                        exibir.value = "<?php $phpvar='"+valor+"';
                        echo $phpvar;?>";
                    } 
<input id="preco" type="number" name="valorunitario" value="">

Comment: Show! Tenta bolar uma lógica pra deixar esse javascript em um arquivo externo, para melhores performances, já que ele entrará no cache do navegador.